# Does Hive SELECT Query return data in random order like in RDBMS?

Tags: hive

I have a table in Hive loaded using a text file. If i do a (SELECT * FROM TABLE),
will i get the data in order as it is stored in file or it could be random. I am not using any ORDER BY.

Is it same like in RDBMS where we must use ORDER BY if we need output in desired format.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? How likely is it to even be stored in the desired order?

Comment: In the case of your trivial `SELECT * ` with no filter, if you have a *single* text file (smaller than 1 HDFS block) then Hive will read it sequentially. Same thing with a RDBMS, except the size limit is much smaller (e.g. 8KB page for SQL Server). But as soon as you can read the blocks/pages in different orders, or using different paths (e.g. thru indexes, or having to wait for locks to be released) then it's not deterministic any more.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter this could be an answer.